# Shiro not redirecting to loginUrl after failed attempts to log in

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, shiro, spring-boot-actuator

Using Spring Boot I am configuring the following filter

```
@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMapping = new HashMap<>();

    /*
    * URL path expressions are evaluated against an incoming request in the order they are defined and the FIRST MATCH WINS. For example, let's asume that there are the following chain definitions:
         /account/** = ssl, authc
         /account/signup = anon
      If an incoming request is intended to reach /account/signup/index.html (accessible by all 'anon'ymous users), it will never be handled!. The reason is that the /account/** pattern matched the incoming request first and 'short-circuited' all remaining definitions.
      Always remember to define your filter chains based on a FIRST MATCH WINS policy!
    * */

    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/login.html", "authc");
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/logout", "logout");
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/css/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/register/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/**", "authc");
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMapping);
    shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());

    shiroFilter.setLoginUrl("/login.html");
    shiroFilter.setSuccessUrl("/");
    shiroFilter.setUnauthorizedUrl("/unauthorized.html");

    Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();

    filters.put("anon", new AnonymousFilter());

    filters.put("authc", new FormAuthenticationFilter());

    LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter();
    logoutFilter.setRedirectUrl("/login.html?logout");
    filters.put("logout", logoutFilter);

    filters.put("roles", new RolesAuthorizationFilter());
    filters.put("user", new UserFilter());

    shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);

    return shiroFilter;
}
```

However, whenever I try to login with wrong credentials the redirection never happens. I do get the "shiroLoginFailure" attribute holding the UnknownUserException.

(Logging in with the correct credentials works fine)

Any ideas?

Comment: `FormAuthenticationFilter`'s `onLoginFailure()` method does not do any redirection, so that servlet's filter chain ends up going into Spring framework's code. Since you don't implement any RequestMapping on the "loginUrl", it returns 404 error. One solution is to subclass `FormAuthenticationFilter` to redefine `onLoginFailure()`, letting it do redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Mariosk89, how do you resolve the `/login.html`?

It might be need to resolve redirect like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(String username, String password) {
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(username) && StringUtils.hasText(password)) {
        try {
            currentUser.login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return "login";
        }
        return "redirect:index";
    } else {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/lenicliu/examples/tree/master/examples-spring-boot/examples-spring-boot-shiro

For more exception solution, refer http://shiro.apache.org/10-minute-tutorial.html

```
try {
    currentUser.login( token );
    //if no exception, that's it, we're done!
} catch ( UnknownAccountException uae ) {
    //username wasn't in the system, show them an error message?
} catch ( IncorrectCredentialsException ice ) {
    //password didn't match, try again?
} catch ( LockedAccountException lae ) {
    //account for that username is locked - can't login.  Show them a message?
} 
    ... more types exceptions to check if you want ...
} catch ( AuthenticationException ae ) {
    //unexpected condition - error?
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The way that you propose includes controller that would handle the log in procedure. This is always an option but I'd expect Shiro to be able to handle this by itself. In my current implementation I don't have such a controller but I think that this is the only way to do it anyway. I am not sure if I have to use a PassThruFilter or a FormAuthenticationFilter

Comment: plus, your solution uses a Templating Engine (freemaker) which is something that I want to avoid